# Android prevent scrollview from scrolling to videoView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview, android-scrollview

If the video is hidden, the scroll view acts as expected - it stays scrolled to the top. However, if the video is loaded, the scroll view jumps to that video. I tried disabling all focusability on the VideoView but no luck. Is there something on Video view that disables this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out right after posting... need to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

In my case, it had to go on the LinearLayout that contained the scroll view that contained the VideoView