# How to prevent Android ViewPager2 scrolling automatically to a page with VideoView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-viewpager2

I have video view on a ViewPager2 page (at index=2). When I try to show the fragment containing the ViewPager2, the ViewPager2 auto scrolls to that page.

Comment: You should post your code with your question so we can try to find out the issue

Comment: @NileshRathod It is just a straight forward implementation. I am suspecting that it is related this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159766/android-prevent-scrollview-from-scrolling-to-videoview

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to prevent the autoscroll by doing this

```
val recyclerViewOfViewPager2 = (0 until viewPager2.childCount)
    .mapNotNull { viewPager2.getChildAt(it) as? RecyclerView }
    .firstOrNull()
recyclerViewOfViewPager2?.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS
```